# Java main class initiate another main class

Tags: java, methods, call, program-entry-point

I have two different java packages, one with a main class which calls another public class and then a second package which just has a main class. 
The issue is that I would like the package with one main class to call the main class in the other package to then initiate it. 
I tried doing it using the code below, but it obviously does not work as the two different classes aren't in the same package.

```
String[] args = {};
myMainClassNumber2.main(args);
```

Comment: Import the other class? `main` isn't special in any way.

Comment: While the solution below isn't wrong, it may be wiser to take the common code out into a single class and use the objects from this class it in both main methods. It helps you create reusable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell the compiler what package the other class is in.

Either

```
import your.pkg.myMainClassNumber2;

public static void main(String[] myArgs) {
  String[] args = {};
  myMainClassNumber2.main(args);
}
```

or

```
public static void main(String[] myArgs) {
  String[] args = {};
  your.pkg.myMainClassNumber2.main(args);
}
```